# Entourage MyDay replacement

Tags: ical, ms-office

I am migrating from Entourage to Mac Mail. Entourage has a tool called MyDay which is quite handy for getting an overview over my appointments first day in the morning.

Is there a competitive product available which snycronizes with iCal appointments and todo list?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found one app which could do the job on the app store, it's called "[Today - Daily Calendar & Task Manager](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/today-daily-calendar-task/id402490288?mt=12)"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This software, iDeskCal](http://www.hashbangind.com/ideskcal.php) might do it. It gives you access to iCal on your desktop, but it's unclear to me if it supports to-dos.

Comment: The problem with this application is that my desktop is cluttered with folders and Files, so I wont be able to see iDeskCal